# from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter generates error as cannot import name 'ORDER_PATTERN' from 'django.db

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-filters

I found out that the line `from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter` generates me an error as

```
 from django.db.models.sql.constants import ORDER_PATTERN
ImportError: cannot import name 'ORDER_PATTERN' from 'django.db.models.sql.constants' (E:\anaconda\envs\AHG_web\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\constants.py)
```

I used that as below:

```
class op_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet) :
    # permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    queryset = Op.objects.all().filter()
    serializer_class = op_Serializer
    # authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication , SessionAuthentication , BasicAuthentication]
    # pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    # pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend , SearchFilter]
    filter_class = op_filter
    ordering_fields = ['close_date' , ]
    ordering = ['close_date']
    search_fields = ['website' , 'title' , 'description' , 'organization__name']

    @action(detail=True , methods=['Get'])
    def attachments(self , request , pk) :
        op = self.get_object()
        links = Attachments.objects.filter(op_id=op.id)
        serializer = attachments_Serializer(links , many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

previously it was working fine, can anyone help me with the solution.

Comment: What versions of Django and the rest framework do you have installed?

Comment: @lain Shelvington (3, 1, 5, 'final', 0)

Comment: And the version of rest_framework?

Comment: There are issues with django_filters and django > 3, which have since been fixed.  Did you recently upgrade django, but not django_filters?

Comment: From a quick search its seems that this is probably a DRF being outdated issue: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/7259

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a compatibility problem between the versions of Django and Django Rest Framework. Upgrading to the latest version of DRF should resolve it.

(I had this error after upgrading Django 3.0.x to 3.2)

Answer (score 0):

Update all packeges you have installed in your project

```
pip install <package_name> --upgrade
```